# How to remove floating label from TextInputLayout with OutlinedBox style?

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

Is there way to remove floating label (hint) when the `TextInputLayout` is in focused mode?

When I try to set `app:hintEnabled="false"` and hint inside `TextInputeEditText`, the `TextInputLayout` behaves weird by hiding top stroke.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Text">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Important thing is that I use Material Components in version `1.1.0-alpha01.`

**Edit**

This is what it looks like (when input is not focused):

[image: Screenshot]

Top stroke is cut.

Comment: set hint to edittext and not textinputlayout and set hintenabled to false

Comment: Did you see what I mentioned above code part?

Comment: because you are setting hint to textinputlayout and not textinputedittext.

Comment: I've done like you said. Stroke is still hiding.

Comment: set hint for edittext and  app:hintEnabled="false" for textinputlayout. that works for me

Comment: Do you use Material Components?

Comment: yes i use the same

Comment: Can you provide code with screenshots? It's not working for me.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ggf2zjmm

Comment: and looks like https://ibb.co/RhMGR76

Comment: See edited question. Your solution works only when input is focused (red color).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187544/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-nominalista).

Answer (score 7):

Yes there's a rather simple way to remove the floating label hint and only have a hint inside your `TextInputLayout`.

This can be easily achieved by disabling the hint in the `TextInputLayout`, and setting the hint on the `TextInputEditText` instead of the `TextInputLayout` like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint text comes here" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The result looks something like this: [image]

And when some text is added, it will look like this: [image]

I tried this out in Material Components v1.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Just set hint for `EditText` **programmatically** and remove `app:hintEnabled="false"` from your `TextInputLayout` if you have, in my case worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to **set hint empty of both** text layout and edit text:-

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint=""
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

If you **want to use** hint then you can **use custom drawable as background of EditText** :-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:color="#000000"
    android:width="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: But I want to keep hint in a EditText.

Comment: you can use custom drawable with stroke and white background

Answer (score 0):

**You should use this style in first :**

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">20dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">20dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">20dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">20dp</item>
</style>
```

**And you should have textinputlayout that contain this style like this :**

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativelayout_activatetoken_main"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/activatetoken_passwordhint"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
        app:helperText="@string/activatetoken_passwordhelpertext"
        app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceHelper"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceBase"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/text_50">
```

**And for the border color use this in colors :**

```
 <color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#F5F5F5</color>
```